# Git: Find out which branch contains a commit and check it out?

Tags: git, git-submodules

From what I've learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891069) about submodules, I can now roll my submodules back to the right commit by using

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

however, now the submodules are never (rarely?) in a branch. I **think** that which branch the submodule needs is not stored. Anyway, I can use

```
git branch --contains HEAD
```

in the submodule and figure out the branch and then switch to it. Is there a built-in way to this? My goal is to get back to a branch that contains the commit (if there is one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Git doesn't track submodules by branches, it tracks them by commits. So `git submodule update` will result in the submodules being in a detached HEAD state (similar to if you `git checkout` a specific commit hash). Before doing any work, you'll have to make sure to actually check out a branch, otherwise things could get messy.

As of Git 1.8.2, you can now have submodules track branches. This option needs to be specified when you add the submodule:

`git submodule add -b master <git repo url>`

If you track submodules via branches, you'll want to add `--remote` to the update call:

`git submodule update --remote`

You can read more about tracking submodules via branches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/506338) and [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html#submodules).

Comment: @Yar I should note that I have *not* tested this method, especially when it comes to rolling back (as your previous question stated you were doing), so I'm definitely interested in finding out if it works as expected. Submodules are always an, er, *adventure*, to put it mildly.

Comment: Understood. I just updated to git 1.8.2 so I can test it, but the previous answer got me 99% of where I needed to get. I might just make another little script called `git-checkout-branch-that-contains-head` (that's its full name) and call it a day. ;)